# How to check an array for values similars to a given string?

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting, similarity

Currently working on a project doing the following:

1. Fetch the most common phrases between 2 and 5 words in a large body of text (all good)
2. Return an array with $phrase => $occurrences

I now want to take each value in this array and check if there is a similar one in the rest of the array and if so, merge them into one and sum up their occurrences.

I want to use **similar_text()** to compares how similar to phrases are and if it is > 95, then I want to merge them.

What's the most efficient way to do this? I am trying to optimise by the millisecond.

For now, I am using this... but it sucks with 10/30k-words articles. Especially as I am looping through dozens of them.

```
function merge_similar_phrases( $original, $threshold = 90 ) {

    foreach ( $original as $phrase => $occurrences ) {

        foreach ( $original as $s => $n ) {

            similar_text( $phrase, $s, $percent );

            if( $percent > 92.5 ) {

                $original[$phrase] = $occurrences + $n;
                unset( $original[$s] );

            }

        }

    }

    return $original;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: which is your current approach?

Comment: Unfortunately text similarity functions have pretty poor running time in PHP. Levenshtein, for example, has a worst case O(nm).

Comment: you can't "optimize" similar_text(). it does what it does, and you can't change that without optimizing the underlying php source code, which means compiling your own custom php version.

Comment: @Nadir i edited original and added my approach

Answer (score 0):

to increase performance you could save yourself one foreach loop and replace it with array_filter. i have in mind something like this:

```
foreach ( $original as $phrase => $occurrences ) {

    $similarities = array_filter($original, function($key) use($phrase, $threshold) {
        similar_text( $phrase, $key, $percent );
        if($percent > $threshold){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    unset($similarities[$phrase]);
    //do the magic with similarities
}
```

You have to use php 5.6+ to be able to use ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY flag (as mentioned in docs.: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

But i am not sure how much time you can spare by doing it..